# Rebalancing fast with mongodb

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I am implementing a sharding with MongoDB and have recently added another node, but the rebalancing of data is very slow. Servers have 64 Mac OS with RAM.

I need help on how I can run the `mongod` process faster.

Comment: Please provide more detail. What do you mean by slow. How much RAM do you have? Also update your post with configuration

Comment: Plus: a) Please do no [double-post here and on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36074962/rebalancing-fast-with-mongodb). b) If you are told to add more information, as you were on SO, please do so. c) I hope your Mac OS (which I assume to be OSX, really) has RAM. ;) As a rule of thumb: you should _at least_ put as much effort into your question as you expect others to put into their answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, mongod <3.4 have slow balancing speed because of "internal throttling", but if you do your balancing work with script (using MoveChunk-command) it's much faster.

However, if you upgrade your system to 3.4 series, balancing will be about 10x faster and even faster if you have multiple shards (>=4)